# Google VMS - Vehicle Map Service

Tags: google-maps, android-automotive

Where can I find more detailed documentation about Google VMS - Vehicle Map Service?

According to this page: https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/properties#vms it is part of VHAL 2.0. However, I could not find additional information about it.

Answer (score 0):

Google VMS doesn't seem to have any published documentation. However you can browse its [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/master/car-lib/src/android/car/vms). It is well-documented and has Javadoc comment. You can also download the source code and generate documentation from Javadoc yourself if you wish.